Trying to find pythonic way to partially fill numpy array
I have a numpy array psi of shape (3,1000)
psi.__class__
Out[115]: numpy.ndarray

psi.shape
Out[116]: (3, 1000)

I want to partially fill psi with another array b
b.__class__
Out[113]: numpy.ndarray

b.shape
Out[114]: (3, 500)

I can do this with a loop:
for n in range(3):
   psi[n][:500] = b[n]

But it seems to me that there ought to be a way to do this more directly.  But for instance
psi[:][:500] = b

fails with error
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-120-6b23082d9d6b>", line 1, in <module>
    psi[:][:500] = b

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3,500) into shape (3,1000)

I've a few variations on the theme as well, with similar results.  This seems pretty straightforward.  Any idea how to do it?

p[:, :500] = b?

Oh crap.  That was easy.  I'm embarrassed!  Thanks. Make it an answer and I'll accept!

You can use:
psi[:, :500] = b

Or, if n (=3) in your loop does not match the first dimension of b:
idx = np.arange(3)
psi[idx, :500] = b[idx]

Comparing the two approaches (psi1 with the loop, psi2 as vectorial assignment):
np.allclose(psi1, psi2)
# True

